# Python/Plotly recompile button

Tags: python, random, plotly

I'm not sure this is the correct place to ask this question, but I'm hoping someone here will have a useful or better idea.

I use python to randomly generate data, and then I use plotly to plot this data. Every time I compile the code, the output plot changes, as expected. If I make this html public, every user will always see the same plot, although based on random data. I would like to somehow include a button or some widget into the output html file of plotly that allows the user to `recompile'. That is, the user loads the webpage, sees a plot, clicks the 're-compile' button, and the page (possibly refreshes and) displays the new plot based on new random data.

Is such a thing possible? If a button isn't possible, is there a way of having the code re-run every time the page is launched? Or maybe there's a better way of achieving this?

Thanks

Comment: If the code is re-run on reload, just reload the page on click or every N seconds. This can be done in JavaScript in one or two lines.

Comment: @ForceBru Thanks, but that's the part I don't know how to do--how to have the code re-run on reload.

Comment: well, then, first of all, please provide us with a [mcve] and, secondly, add as much details as possible and in the most succinct way you can.